# Intuition behind the exponential loss function

Tags: statistics, intuition, machine-learning

I'm reading about AdaBoost from the book *The Elements of Statistical Learning*.
The book mentions that, to train the model, the exponential loss function is used:
$$L(y, f (x)) = e^{−y f (x)},$$
where $y$ is the expected output and $f(x)$ is the model output given the feature $x$.
The problem I have understanding this loss function is that "same errors" give different loss.

For example,

$y=1$ and $f(x)=0.8$ then $L(y, f (x)) = e^{−0.8}$

$y=0$ and $f(x)=.2$ then $L(y, f (x)) = e^{0.2} \neq e^{−0.8}$

In both cases, $y-f(x)= 0.2$, but the loss functions give different values.

Could anyone tell me what I'm missing here?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Note the multiplicative form, exponential loss function is meant for classification.

$y$ should be either $1$ or $-1$.

If $y=1$, $f(x)=0.8$, $L(y, f(x))=e^{-0.8}$.

If $y=-1$, $f(x)=-0.8$, $L(y, f(x))=e^{-0.8}$.

If you share the same sign as the truth as have large magnitude, we want the value to be small.